# Error when running app after updating gradle version - Task :app:generatePackageList FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm newbie using react-native and I've been trying to update the gradle version for a few days now..

Currently I use version 6.5, my react-native version is: 0.60.0 I need to update gradle from version 6.5 to version 7.2, but when trying to run the application using this new version of gradle I get the following error:

```
> Task :app:generatePackageList FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
82 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 81 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/projects/xxxxxx/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 137

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'.
> argument type mismatch
```

In some places I read that possibly the react-native-community version is not compatible with the 7x version of gradle, but I'm still a little lost on the subject and I'm looking for new information.

Thanks in advance for all the help!